# Weird error when attempting to load fonts from django server from local file

Tags: css, django, fonts

I'm trying to serve fonts to an ionic app. Ionic apps run from the phone so the origin is 'file://' (for all CORS matters it's 'null').

I have a font face defined in a css file served from the server

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Ionicons;
    src: url(/static/assets/fonts/ionicons/ionicons.eot?v=2.0.1);
    src: url(/static/assets/fonts/ionicons/ionicons.eot?v=2.0.1#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),
         url(/static/assets/fonts/ionicons/ionicons.ttf?v=2.0.1) format("truetype"),
         url(/static/assets/fonts/ionicons/ionicons.woff?v=2.0.1) format("woff"),
         url(/static/assets/fonts/ionicons/ionicons.woff) format("woff"),
         url(/static/assets/fonts/ionicons/ionicons.svg?v=2.0.1#Ionicons) format("svg");
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal
}
```

And this is the error i get in the server:

```
[16/Jan/2016 15:30:52] "GET /static/assets/fonts/ionicons/ionicons.woff HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 63567)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 179, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 278, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 452, in _write
    self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 394, in write
    return self._sock.send(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "c:\src\ravkav-store\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 95, in handle_error
    super(ServerHandler, self).handle_error()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 367, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 179, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 273, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 330, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 343, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socketserver.py", line 617, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socketserver.py", line 344, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "c:\src\ravkav-store\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 102, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socketserver.py", line 673, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "c:\src\ravkav-store\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 182, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

This is most likely an issue with the development server because it work when serving the files from nginx.

Comment: ionicons doesn't run from the phone, the fact that [their webpage](http://ionicons.com/#cdn) provides a cdn is proof that this isn't the case

Comment: As I said, i'm serving it from my own server. If i put `localhost:8000/static/assets/fonts/ionicons/ionicons.woff` i get the file. the problem is the origin.

Comment: simplify this: it's 2016, every browser that's still supported supports .woff fonts. Ditch the eot (only supported by old, and as of Jan 12th 2016, *abandoned* versions of IE), svg (an abandoned format by *everyone* for years now), and ttf/otf (already wrapped byte-for-byte by woff, but with optional lossless compression). Especially if this is for phones, [every phone post Android 4.3](http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff) fully supports woff. The other formats are not needed. That'll also help you reduce your problem surface area.